# Stuttering visuals

Tags: 14.04

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask for this kind of help, but I am getting stuttering visuals from time to time and can't deduce the reason.

I bought/build my pc about two-three months ago so it's quite new. Didn't buy a separate gpu, since I didn't think I'd need any. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (upgraded from 12.04 last month). Most of the time cpu usage is about 15-30% on all four cores, memory usages is about 15-20% and I'm using an SSD internal disk. With these numbers I wouldn't expect to have much lag from anything, when just browsing the web, yet at random times the pc seems to stutter or freeze for a sec. For example something opening the file browser goes fast, other times it goes fast, I have had gif files playing fine, but then randomly slow down. The most noticable thing that I think shouldn't be happening is when I am typing a large text like I'm doing now and the letters showing slows down. Typing shouldn't result in much delay shouldn't it? It's like the computer is having hiccups at random occasions, but I can't track down why.

I didn't have this problem before and I just started noticing it recently. Did it start when I upgraded to 14.04? Another example would be when I used compizconfig manager again after updating, every time I changed a setting it would freeze the screen for a few minutes before working again. This problem has gone away now. I also tried using other lightweight desktops, thinking that maybe that would make a difference, but the problem was still there. So basically I have tried random, probably unrelated stuff, wasting my time not knowing where to start looking.

I'm thinking of just downloading and reinstalling 14.04 from scratch since I'm working with an upgraded version of 12.04 now, hoping this will fix things, but before I do something that drastic, does anybody know how I could possibly track the problem down? I don't believe a quadcore computer with enough ram would possible stutter when typing a text like this... The thing is that the problem just suddenly appeared, while the computer had been working perfectly for a month or two. Did I maybe install something I shouldn't have? Or might some hardware be malfunctioning maybe? I don't know. Hope anybody can point me in the direction or can help me out. That would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
user@PC:/var/log$ cat syslog | grep -i warning
May 23 13:45:50 PC gnome-session[16809]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
May 23 13:45:50 PC gnome-session[16809]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly

user@PC:/var/log$ cat syslog | grep -i error
May 23 13:45:50 PC kernel: [13458.470094] compiz[17051]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f0e7659a000 sp 00007fffea049940 error 6 in libunityshell.so[7f0e76260000+53c000]

user@PC:/var/log$ cat kern.log | grep -i "May 23" | grep -i warning
May 23 10:01:34 PC kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Optional FADT field Pm2ControlBlock has zero address or length: 0x0000000000000000/0x1 (20131115/tbfadt-603)
May 23 10:01:48 PC kernel: [   17.506884] deprecated_sysctl_warning: 168 callbacks suppressed
May 23 10:01:48 PC kernel: [   17.506889] warning: process `vmware-hostd' used the deprecated sysctl system call with 1.1.

user@PC:/var/log$ cat kern.log | grep -i "May 23" | grep -i error
May 23 10:01:34 PC kernel: [    2.356186] nct6775: probe of nct6775.656 failed with error -16
May 23 10:01:34 PC kernel: [    2.933570] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
May 23 13:45:50 PC kernel: [13458.470094] compiz[17051]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f0e7659a000 sp 00007fffea049940 error 6 in libunityshell.so[7f0e76260000+53c000]

user@PC:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i warning
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 16747.020] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[ 16747.020] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module modesetting
[ 16747.020] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[ 16747.021] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[ 16747.021] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[ 16747.021] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module modesetting
[ 16747.022] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[ 16747.022] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa

peter@PC:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i error
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 16747.587] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[ 16747.587] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[ 16747.587] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
```

**Additional Drivers says:**

Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]

- Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog`? If you create a new user account and login to it, do you still get stuttering? What GPU do you have and what drivers are you using?

Comment: @bain I added the error/warning log and gpu. I'll try a new user now. (Note that I am writing this at 14:21 to compare the times with)

Comment: compiz segfault. What version of fglrx do you have installed?

Comment: `user@PC:~$ ls /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/` ->
`13.350.1  kernel-3.11.0-20-generic-x86_64  kernel-3.13.0-24-generic-x86_64`

Comment: You could try uninstalling the closed driver and using the open source driver? But I do not know how well it will work with 14.04 on your hardware. Also check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for any errors. You could also try purging all copies of the fglrx driver and reinstalling it.

Comment: As for now it seems to be going okay. Don't get any errors anymore either. Hope it'll last. I'll re-install and clean my ubuntu anyway, but thanks for telling me about those log files, they are quite useful!

Answer (score 0):

I do have exactly the same issue with almost the same hw configuration. It appears to me, that the issue got worse in Ubuntu 14.04 and firefox 33. A significant part of the issue seems to be caused by firefox (33) and in particular by the flash plugin which I deactivated eventually. But that doesn't fix the problem entirely. 
The "stutter" comes in short and steady intervals, every few seconds, especially if firefox is running for a few hours already. It affects all applications. LibreOffice users may notice the exact same behaviour when typing, as described above by Peter Raeves.

The first I would do is to

1. configure LibreOffice and increase the cache memory and
2. deactivate the flash plugin in firefox and restart firefox.

Firefox can be further optimized by opening a new tab and enter `about:config`. 
Then set `network.http.pipelining` to `true`, set `network.http.prox.pipelining` to `true`, set `network.dns.disableIPV6` to `false`. That will provide some improvement (but still not fix it entirely).

I wonder if anyone else has experienced a similar issue and if the root cause, respectively resolution was found. It would be great if Mozilla finally was able to fix this issue that is plaguing Ubuntu users for years now.

Comment: I dont really use FF or LO that much, rather I use chrome and latex/google docs. In the end I just figured the hiccups must be because I have a dual screen setup with a total resolution higher than the max resolution my builtin gpu supports... the problem really got worse during gaming so I ended up gaming on my laptop. I should try with a single monitor and see if the problem remains though.